# UIImageView's shadow gets bigger than intended when shadowPath is set

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, calayer, shadow

```
CGRect rect = biggerImageView.bounds;
if([biggerImageView.layer respondsToSelector:@selector(setShadowColor:)])
{
    float shadowOffset = rect.size.width * 0.02;
    biggerImageView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite: 0.25 alpha: 0.55].CGColor;
    biggerImageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(shadowOffset, shadowOffset);
    biggerImageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
    //      biggerImageView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect: rect].CGPath;                                                                                                                                                                            
}
```

The commented out line causes the shadow becomes bigger than intended.
(vertically longer shadows on top and bottom)
I looked up CALayer reference but got no clue there.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same results trying to make a category method on UIView to add drop shadows.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because the `UIView` `bounds` is not the real one yet. (Like in `awakeFromNib` or `viewDidLoad`)

Wait for the view `layoutSubviews` or viewController `viewWillLayoutSubviews` to be called, and update the path of your shadow there.

I created this swift extension to add the same shadow (with `cornerRadius` support) everywhere I need to :

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    /// Call this from `layoutSubviews` or `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.
    /// The shadow will be the same color as this view background.
    func layoutShadow() {

        // Update frame
        if let shadowView = superview?.viewWithTag(978654123) {
            shadowView.frame = frame
            shadowView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
            return
        }

        // Create the shadow the first time
        let shadowView = UIView(frame: frame)
        shadowView.tag = 978654123
        shadowView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        superview?.insertSubview(shadowView, belowSubview: self)

        shadowView.layer.shadowColor = (backgroundColor ?? UIColor.black).cgColor
        shadowView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
        shadowView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -2.0, height: 4.0)
        shadowView.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0
        shadowView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
    }
}
```